# Django tutorial part 3 - bad link or directory structure

Tags: django

I'm doing the tutorial at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/

It says to make a templates directory under the polls application (which is under 'mysite'), such that I have a tree that looks like this:

```
mysite
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
    polls
        migrations
        templates
            polls
                index.html
        views.py
        models.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        manage.py
```

In the template they want me to write:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="polls/{{  question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available</p>
{% endif %}
```

The page loads, but if I click the link it wants to take me to 'localhost:8000/polls/polls/1'
and that does not exist.

There are one too many '/polls'
Question is, was the template directory supposed to go one level higher, under mysite? or should be not have '/polls' in the hyperlink?

Despite their little explanation, I do not understand why we'd want to have 'polls/templates/polls'. It seems to me that we can tell it is polls if it is under polls already.

mysite/urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

Comment: Post your urls.py file as well.

Comment: added url.py files to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't in your URL configuration or project directory structure: change your link from

`<li><a href="polls/{{  question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>`

to

`<li><a href="/polls/{{  question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>`

(as in, add the slash)

The reason is that without that slash, the link is referenced as relative to the current URL, so when you click the link `/polls` becomes `/polls/whateverTheHREFwas`

Regarding the purpose of the directory structure: you want the `index.html` file to be namespaced within the polls directory because of the way Django discovers templates. Say you had two applications: `polls` and `answers` and had an `index.html` for each. You'd want `polls/index.html` and `results/index.html` to be the names of the files you reference in your views because otherwise you (and Django) would have no idea which `index.html` you're referencing.

Comment: But if I had two applications, wouldn't I have templates folder in each?
mysite/polls/templates/index.html and mysite/answers/templates/index.html?

Comment: To some extent you're accommodating Django's template discovery structure. The way it works is that you tell Django (by having `APP_DIRS=True` in your settings file) that it should look for all templates within the `templates` directory of each of your apps. In the structure you mentioned in the comment above, it would say "Okay I looked for `index.html` in your app directories and I found two and am now confused about which one to use". But if you namespace your templates within a subdirectory of `mysite/polls/templates/polls/index.html`and reference `polls/index.html` there's no ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid path mistakes like the one here where you're missing the leading slash (`polls/<id>/` vs `/polls/<id>/` you can instead use the `url` template tag to generate the url based on the url name and the arguments. This also future proofs your templates in case you decide to change the path configuration.

E.g.

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url "detail" question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available</p>
{% endif %}
```

Even better would be to define a `get_absolute_url` method on your `Question` model as recommended in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

```
# models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('polls.views.detail', self.id) 

# template
 <li><a href="{{ question.get_absolute_url }}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```